# i can't send modelAttribute that contains a mapped object from another class

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have a problem in a matter concerning a mapped object.
here are the entities used:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "skill")
public class Skill {
   .
   .
   @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name = "collab_id")
   private Collaborateur collaborateur;

........................
@Entity
@Table(name = "collaborateur")
public class Collaborateur {
   .
   .
   @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "collaborateur")
   private Skill skill;
```

My jsp file :

```
<form:form action="/app/skill" method="post" modelAttribute="skill"
id="myForm">
<div>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Recherche de skill par critere :</legend>
        .
        .
        .
        <form:select path="collaborateur" id="input" >
            <form:option value="" label="--Collaborateur--"></form:option>
            <form:options path="collaborateur" items="${collaborateurs}" itemLabel="firstname" itemValue="id"/>
        </form:select>  


        <input type="submit" value="Search" name="Search"
            class="searchButton" onclick="pagination('${1}', '${size}')" />
    </fieldset>
```

When i try to search for a "collaborateur" in a "skill" list, using Example from spring data,i get the this error.

```
   org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Path 
   'collaborateur.skill.collaborateur' from root Skill must not span a cyclic 
   property reference!
   [{ com.app.entities.Skill@a648b00 }] -collaborateur-> [{ 
   com.app.entities.Collaborateur@2b }] -skill-> [{ 
   com.app.entities.Skill@33a1c699 }] -collaborateur-> [{ 
   com.app.entities.Collaborateur@2b }]
```

What causing this error ?

Comment: The exception says it all. You created two entities which are pointing to each other. `Skill` has one to one mapping to `Collaborateur ` and `Collaborateur`  has one to one mapping to `Skill`. Hibernate detects this and `fail fast`

Comment: Thx for the clarification @MarcinBukowiecki , how can i fix this if i want to keep the mapping as it is.

Comment: @khalilbouzraa did you manage to solve this?